# creating buttons in jquery in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I'm looking to find a more efficient way to build buttons and assign actions to them. The site I'm working with is written entirely in javascript. I tried to implement this:

```
var test = $('<button/>', {
    text: i, //set text 1 to 10
    id: 'btn_'+i,
    click: function () { alert('hi'); }
});
```

but I get an error "Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8". Does anyone have a terse solution to creating buttons with actions assigned in Javascript? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QY7HD/. You code works fine.. Which version of jquery you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "terse solution", 
Try this, `$('<button/>').click( function(){}).attr('text',i).attr('id','btn_'+i).appendTo('body')`
(Pls fill in the loop and other stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    var test = $('<button/>', {
        text: i, //set text 1 to 10
        id: 'btn_'+i,
        click: function () { alert('hi'); }
    });
    $('body').append(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8"

error because you haven't set `i` in you code..so it is undefined...

```
 var test = $('<button/>', {
   text: i, //set text 1 to 10 //<----here
   id: 'btn_'+i,
   click: function () { alert('hi'); }
 });
```

if you need i to be values of 1 - 10 then you can use loop

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
   var test = $('<button/>', {
     text: i, //set text 1 to 10 //<----here
     id: 'btn_'+i,
     click: function () { alert('hi'); }
   });
}
});
```

Comment: grrr... I pasted the wrong code, if I replace i with with a string value the same error is produced. Thanks for the suggestion, I will be testing here in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var i=0;
$(function () {
    var test = $('<button/>', {
        text: i,
        class:'btn',
        id: 'btn_' + i        
    });
    i++;
    var test1 = $('<button/>', {
        text: i, 
        class:'btn',
        id: 'btn_' + i        
    });

    $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('#mydiv').append(test);
    $('#mydiv').append(test1);
});
```

Check working sample on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vijaypatel/QgdsC/